# Why this Angular HttpClient Post doesn't get synchronous?

Tags: angular

Both foo() and addProduct() are methods of same class. addProduct() gets called when a form it's submitted. I was expecting to be displayed first "ok1" and then "ok2" inside Console but it's happening otherwise. I'm doing something wrong?

```
  async foo(url, obj) {
     const result = await this.http.post(url, obj).toPromise();
     return result;
  }

  addProduct(ProductName, ProductDescription, ProductPrice) {
    const obj = {
      ProductName,
      ProductDescription,
      ProductPrice
    };

    this.foo("http://localhost:4000/products/add", obj).then( (result) => {
        console.log("ok1");
    });
    console.log("ok2");
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

foo call is asynchronous so it is obvious that calling method will finish its execution irrespective of foo method call. If you need to call `ok1` first and then `ok2`, then you need to call `ok2` from inside the result handling part of `foo` method call.

see below code

```
async foo(url, obj) {
     const result = await this.http.post(url, obj).toPromise();
     return result;
  }

  addProduct(ProductName, ProductDescription, ProductPrice) {
    const obj = {
      ProductName,
      ProductDescription,
      ProductPrice
    };

    this.foo("http://localhost:4000/products/add", obj).then( (result) => {
        console.log("ok1");
       console.log("ok2"); // this will ensure that ok2 will be always after ok1
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`console.log("ok2")`

is run immediately after sending off the http request. When the http request comes back,

`console.log("ok1")`

is run

Answer (score 0):

Make `addProduct` as **async** method.

> **Note** You are getting unexpected output because http call happen asynchronously.  But the output you getting according to your code is correct. [You can learn more about async JavaScript here (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous)

```js
async foo(url, obj) {
     const result = await this.http.post(url, obj).toPromise();
     return result;
}

async addProduct(ProductName, ProductDescription, ProductPrice) {
    const obj = {
      ProductName,
      ProductDescription,
      ProductPrice
    };

    const result = await this.foo("http://localhost:4000/products/add", obj)
    console.log("ok1");
    console.log("ok2");
}
```